# Difference beetwen assigning properties to element or putting it directly in markup

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference in doing this:

```
<a href="<%=this.GetUserProfilePermalink()%>"><%=this.GetUsername()%></a>
```

and this:

```
<a id="hlUser" runat="server"></a>
```

in codebehind:

```
hlUser.HRef = GetUserProfilePermalink();

hlUser.InnerText = GetUsername();
```

I noticed my codebehind is more readable doing it first way because I moved all assinging to markup however if I miss something somewhere it's hard to find mistake due to "too many character in literal" error.What is the difference and what is the preferable way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the second way of doing it, you will create a Hyperlink object on the server, set some properties on it and then when the page is at the Rendering state it will use the object to render the hyperlink in HTML.

With the first way, you simply emit strings using the Response object, there is no Hyperlink object created on the server.

Even tho the first method is usually more lightweight, the second method has a lot of advantages. For example since you have an object on the server that Renders itself, it can be aware of which browser it is currently rendering it self to, and use different rendering techniques for different browsers so it works everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for response, can you explain "..and use different rendering techniques for different browsers so it works everywhere." I don't quite understand what do you mean.

Answer (score 1):

One of the differences is in the ViewState usage :

Assuming your .GetUserProfilePermalink() is a costly operation, with the first method, you have to run it on each postback.

With the second method, and an active viewstate, you will be able to run .GetUserProfilePermalink() only once and the value will be stored in the viewstate (at a cost in bandwith though) and displayed on each postback.

Also, the code in the markup is not checked during project compilation. On the long run, it is a problem for code refactoring.